# Can't Access DB - Elastic Beanstalk + RDS + VPC (Virtual Private Cloud)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

In trying to move a website to operate via Elastic Beanstalk (ELB), I chose the t2 series of EC2 instances, and in doing so, was forced to create a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). This site connects to a MySQL database via RDS, and I'm not having any luck getting the ELB site to access the database.

I've tried reviewing this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console

The above link starts by saying "works great for development and testing environments, but is not ideal for a production environment", which confuses me as it doesn't say what would be better in its place - I need a database connected to the site!

It has all sorts of information and I tried several of the things it suggested regarding connecting to an existing database (not creating a new one). It mentions on step 6 of the "To modify the ingress rules on your RDS instance's security group" section to access the ingress tab, which doesn't exist for me.

I've tried editing the security group associated with the database via the RDS dashboard under "security groups", but it does not list the security groups that are associated with the VPC or the EC2 instance launched by ELB. I tried pushing the IP addresses, elastic IPs, and still can't get the site to see the database.

I'm at a loss. Can anyone explain how to connect an ELB distributed EC2 instance with an RDS database through the VPC required by t2 instances?

Comment: Is the RDS instance not also in the VPC?

Comment: You need to add the security group of ec2 to rds instance so that ec2 can access it, make sure they are in same vpc also if you have allowed to access the db publicly try to connect from outside if it works.

Comment: Correct, it is not within the VPC - I was trying to access RDS as an external database, as specified by the AWS guide. I tried to add the security group from the EC2, but since it is outside the VPC, it doesn't appear in the list - and that is why I tried giving access by the elastic IP, the EC2 IP, and pretty much any IP I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that "This works great for development and testing environments, but is not ideal for a production environment" is just referring to having ElasticBeanstalk create the RDS instance for you. This can be done by configuring the "Database" section when creating a new EB environment.

The downside of letting EB create the RDS instance for you is that your web instance and database instance will be strongly connected, and if you ever terminate your web instance, your database will also be terminated, including all of your snapshots.

However, I think you're taking the "external" part of "external database" too literally. Your RDS instance should definitely be within the same VPC as your web instance. However, you should create it and connect your web instance to it manually. Connecting to the database involves setting five environment variables (listed below) and configuring the security group to allow connections from the web instance to the database.

The environment variables you'll need to set on your web instance are as follows:

- `RDS_HOSTNAME=instancename.region.rds.amazonaws.com`
- `RDS_DB_NAME=databasename`
- `RDS_PASSWORD=databasepassword`
- `RDS_USERNAME=databaseuser`
- `RDS_PORT=5432`